# How does lightning web component inherit recordId?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am new to Lightning Web Components. I wanted to know how the `@api recordId` gets the recordId from the record. If I change it to `@api recId`, the code does not work.

Does the api fetch the recordId in it just because the name of the public property is recordId? How does it happen? I did not find a satisfactory answer to this question.

```
<!-- myComponent.html -->
<template>
    <lightning-record-form
        record-id={recordId}
        object-api-name="Account"
        layout-type="Compact"
        mode="view">
    </lightning-record-form>
</template> 



// myComponent.js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/use_record_context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `recordId` is a special keyword when used with `@api` in the context of a record page. There are others like `objectApiName`.